# How to use res.data in HTML frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The intention of this route is to render `profile.html` where a user can see all his previous `orders`:

`router.get('/profile', orderController.getOrders)`

I am able to get the orders from Mongo successfully and console.log them but I have no clue as to how to use it to render html elements on `profile.html` to display them.

`res.send(orders)` outputs to the screen and prevents `res.render` from working.

```
module.exports.getOrders = asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {

  const token = req.cookies.jwt
  const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
  const user = decodedToken.id

  const orders = await Order.find( {user: user} )

  res.send(orders)
  res.render('profile.html')
 
})
```

How can I send these `orders` to the front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're missing some information on what framework you're using and how you're compiling your HTML, but typically, you'd skip the `res.send(orders)` and end with `res.render('profile.html', {orders: orders});`  Usually there's a second parameter of items to send to the HTML file, and then the HTML file is compiled with your orders information.  The syntax of that depends on what what HTML compiler you're using. A lot of times you'll find compilers will want input data referenced with double braces, like `{{orders}}`.

I'd recommend looking in your framework documentation to see what parameters render is expecting, and if you need to compile your template before rendering. Hope this, as generic as it is, helps you out!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a view engine to pass the data to front end .

I recommend  using ejs

Comment: I was using ejs for things like the navbar and footer but didnt know this was possible.